# where to find libstdc++.so.5 32-BIT version for SLES 12 on PPC64LE

Tags: linux, libstdc++, powerpc

I need to install on SLES 12 SP2 for IBM PPC64LE the 32-bit version of libstdc++.so.5 and of libstdc++.so.6.

Do you know if they exist and where to find them?
I looked on google but i find only x86 version, i need PPC64LE version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't find a 32-bit libstdc++ for ppc64le because GCC doesn't build it (see [PR 65286](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=65286) for more information).

GCC builds 32-bit runtime libraries for ppc64, but not for ppc64le. As the other answer says, distros do not ship 32-bit user space for ppc64le.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect most of the distros are no longer shipping support for 32-bit environments on POWER, particularly after the change to little-endian. In fact, I don't think there was ever an official 32-bit little-endian ELF ABIv2 defined.

The SLES folks have a [brief document](https://www.suse.com/communities/blog/32-bit-applications-sles-12-yes/)  on 32-bit compatibility, which includes the following about POWER:

> We would note that SLES for Power systems with the change from big endian in SLES 11 to little endian in SLES 12, is ready in SLES 12 for 64-bit applications where that build environment is fully available. **For ISVs currently providing 32-bit applications, having their customers run the 32-bit application on SLES 11 in a virtual image is a good option for their customers running SLES 12 on Power 8 as their base system.**

That first sentence is a bit hard to parse, but it seems like they no longer ship support for 32-bit on LE.

Do you need to build 32-bit?